# How to use composition in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Well here I want to use one method to another component, And for that I found a way through composition.

And this is what I did for that

**file1.js**

```
import ProductList from '../../views/Products/ProductList';

class CloseableTab extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.tpItem = () => {
            console.log("hello, item clicked");
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ProductList
                   itemChange={this.tpItem} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CloseableTab;
```

Then in productList I want to call the "tpItem" method by calling itemChange in prop.
Though before that I tried to console the 'prop' of product list. So, it shows me null object in the console. And for that I used the code below:

**ProductList.js**

```
export default class ProductList extends Component {

constructor() {
        super();
};

render() {
 console.log(this.props);

  return { }
}
}
```

So, this gives me null object in the console.

I'll appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: As none of your 2 components has an internal state, defining them as functions (stateless components) would be recommended as they are easier to read and has better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make constructor `props` enabled ?

Just pass props parameter in constructor

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
```

> The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted.
>   When implementing the constructor for a React.Component subclass, you
>   should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise,
>   this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to
>   bugs.

Comment: OP is not using props in the constructor at all and hence he need not define super(props)

Comment: The OP was calling super() without props... effectively clearing the props of the component

Answer (score 0):

Its not ideal to define functions in the constructor of the component, you can declare them outside of constructor and pass them down, also, in ProductList you are trying to render an object which isn't supported. if you don't want to return anything use `return null`.

Below code works as expected.

```
class CloseableTab extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.tpItem = () => {
      console.log("hello, item clicked");
    };
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.tpItem);
    return (
      <div>
        <ProductList
          itemChange={this.tpItem} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ProductList extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);

    return null
  }
}
```

However you must write it like

```
class CloseableTab extends Component {
  tpItem = () => {
      console.log("hello, item clicked");
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.tpItem);
    return (
      <div>
        <ProductList
          itemChange={this.tpItem} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**[Working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xp01mx030o)**

Comment: About defining the handler outside the constructor like you did... it is *exactly* the same as doing it inside...

Comment: @TiagoCoelho, yes its exactly the same as writing as inside, however its not ideal, since you cannot keep writing all your handlers in constructor